# libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Tags: c++, input

Exercise 4-6 of Accelerated C++ wants me to write a program that reads in and calculates a student's overall grade. I have the following code:

```
// source file for Student_info-related functions
#include "Student_info.h"
#include "grade.h"

using std::istream;  using std::vector;
using namespace std;

bool compare(const Student_info& x, const Student_info& y)
{
    return x.name < y.name;
}

istream& read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
//void read(istream& is, Student_info& s)
{

    double midterm, final;

    // read and store the student's name and midterm and final exam grades
    is >> s.name >> midterm >> final;

    std::vector<double> homework;
    read_hw(is, homework);  // read and store all the student's homework grades

    s.grade = grade(midterm, final, homework);

    cout << "name is: " << s.name << endl;
///    cout << "midterm is: " << midterm << endl;
///    cout << "final is: " << final << endl;
    cout << "grade is: " << s.grade << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;

    return is;
}

// read homework grades from an input stream into a 'vector<double>'
istream& read_hw(istream& in, vector<double>& hw)
{
    cout << "I get into read_hw!" << endl;

    if (in) {
        // get rid of previous contents
        hw.clear();

        // read homework grades
        double x;
        while (in >> x)
            hw.push_back(x);

        // clear the stream so that input will work for the next student
        in.clear();
    }
    cout << "I get (just before) out of read_hw!" << endl;
    return in;
}
```

With the above being called from main() as such:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Student_info> students;
    Student_info record;
    string::size_type maxlen = 0;       // the length of the longest name

    // read and store all the students data.
    // Invariant: students contains all the student records read so far
    //          maxlen contains the length of the longest name in students
    while (read(cin, record)) {
        cout << "Get into read() while loop" << endl;
        // find length of longest name
        maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
        students.push_back(record);
        cout << "Get to end of read() while loop" << endl;
    }
    cout << "I get out of read ok!!" << endl;  // WE NEVER GET THIS FAR
```

Here is the output:

```
(Canopy 32bit) joes-imac:4-6 david$ make test 
./main <data/gradesTest
I get into read_hw!
I get (just before) out of read_hw!
name is: Moo
grade is: 100

Get into read() while loop
Get to end of read() while loop
I get into read_hw!
I get (just before) out of read_hw!
name is: Moore
grade is: 79.4

Get into read() while loop
Get to end of read() while loop
I get into read_hw!
I get (just before) out of read_hw!
name is: Norman
grade is: 72.8

Get into read() while loop
Get to end of read() while loop
I get into read_hw!
I get (just before) out of read_hw!
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
/bin/sh: line 1: 20610 Abort trap: 6           ./main < data/gradesTest
make: *** [test] Error 134
(Canopy 32bit) joes-imac:4-6 david$
```

Why does this fail? Why do we seem to do a blank run (i.e. not read in any data) as the program fails (the data input does not have a blank line at the end or anything like that)?

Comment: Where is the grade function?

Comment: My guess is you're misusing memory somewhere, and something is getting corrupted. You need to identify where exactly it crashes (use a debugger or something like Valgrind), and then you need to provide us with all relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly is your input for the very last loop?  Are you trying to end the loop by sending it non-numeric values for the `midterm` and `final` values?  It looks like your error is happening when you are calculating the grade using those numbers.  My guess would be to try doing this:

```
if (is)
{
    s.grade = grade(midterm, final, homework);
}
```

Comment: Yes the above works... on my input i'm ending the data with a EOF just (at least that is what I think i'm doing!)